# How to build a portal website using Spring MVC potal api?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, portal

I want to build a portal page for an organisation. I have no clue how to do it. I did try google a lot and what i got was 0 results. !!! i want to build a portal and not a portlet!! please help. I do not want use Liferay !!! 
 I have developed a spring-primefaces application, i want to deploy it as a portlet, but how do i build a portal. i m going mad! Somebody help

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried Liferay, but its a portal of its own. So not accepatable. I have to create a portal not use an existing portal , plus, when i googled all i got was portlet development and not portal.. Please help!! Please!